# Java Scanner constructor is ambiguous

Tags: java, constructor, java.util.scanner

I have a static scanner for my class and I imported `java.util.*`.

I declared my Scanner:

```
private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Netbeans (7.1) won't compile because Reference to scanner is ambiguous, both constructor `Scanner(java.io.inputStream)` in `java.util` and constructor `Scanner(path)` in `java.util` match

How can System.in be interpreted as a path? How do I overcome this?

Comment: Do you have a variable called `System` or anything like that? Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: It is completely working fine, There might some other isseu. Post the error stacktrece.

Comment: I have no variables named system, this is my only global variable. What do you mean by showing a program demonstrating the problem ? Thanks

Comment: did you import all packages correctly ?

Comment: Yep i did import java.util.*;  Weirdest part, the code worked perfectly fine like 30 min ago, and suddenly out of nowhere i get this and i really really dont get it. It got weirder whe nm y friend tried the exact same code, on the exact same Neatbeans version and java version and it worked on his computer....

Comment: @WizardLizard post stacktrace with error message

Comment: Does Netbeans have an own Java compiler? Can you compile using the command line?

Comment: @WizardLizard: looks more like an issue with NetBeans than with your code. Is there something like "Clean project" in NetBeans? I would start there

Comment: @StefanHanke yes Netbeans does have its own java compiler, i can try using command line but later only.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet tried clean/clean and built, none made the trick

Comment: I would guess then that "about 30 min ago" you changed something that caused this issue. What did you last write before that that may have caused this?

Comment: @SamDeHaan Actually i (ctrl + z) went back at the very begining of my session and the error remained.

Comment: Clean your project and rebuild

Comment: How about removing static keyword?
Why you want to use scanner without instantiating the actual class?
That sounds suspicious.

Comment: Please create a [mcve], read [help] and [ask], thanks.